# Saving tags as a bit field in MySQL. With index?

Tags: mysql, tags, bit-manipulation, bit-fields, bitset

I am trying to design a tag-like structure for my project using MySQL.

After reading this http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/TagSchema I feel very disappointed because the m2m table design requires so many `join` the performance sure sucks on large data.

What I have in mind is a tag table, where each tag has a `name` and an `id`

Then on the items table I want to tag, each item has a column called `tag`, Each tag marks its bit index as 1, else bit field is 0.

For example

```
table: tag

id   name
1    tag1
2    tag2
3    tag3



table: item

id      name    tag (in binary)     tag (in array)
 1      item1   00000001            [tag1]
 2      item2   00000100            [tag3]
 3      item3   00000110            [tag2, tag3]
```

so if I want to lookup an `item` with certain tags, I only need to `&` the binary tag field with wanted tag `id`.

1. Is my design good idea or bad?
2. Could I use index on the tag bitset field, so I can speed up lookups?
3. If MySQL can not do #2, what's my best option (besides NoSQL)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, the two joins required for a many-to-many relationship do not suck on large data, it's a fundamental design pattern and MySQL is exceptionally fast at joining. Your design breaks if there are more than 32 different tags (or 64, if you use the `BigInt` data type) - can you spot why? Also, it's usually better to worry about implementing your application first and to care about performance later when it becomes an issue.

Comment: I am not going do use int or bitint, I am going to use binary field. Your design is not good because for the average of 3 tags per item, if you item table has 1m rows, you have to scan 3m rows for the tag id, then scan the tag table for the actual tag name.

Comment: No, I don't have to scan millions of rows because every foreign key has an index assigned to it automatically (and it it hadn't, I sure would assign one). So if the task is to find all tags for an item of which you know the id, MySQL would need on the order of `log(3m)` operations to find all tag ids for the item and another `log(number of different tags)` to find the tag names. If you want to use `BINARY`, MySQL will require an index length, so your schema still dictates the max number of different tags.